# Output giving multiple values of each number when they should be single values

Tags: c#, class, output, primes

I'm learning C and C#. This question is for C#. This code from a book I'm reading gives the wrong output. The picture in the book gives output of only one instance of each number, but my code gives multiple instances of each number output. Is it something wrong with my computer?

Here is the class code:

```
namespace practice_6  
{
public class Primes
{
    private long min;
    private long max;

    public Primes()
        : this(2, 100)
    {
    }

    public Primes(long minimum, long maximum)
    {
        if (min < 2)
            min = 2;
        else
            min = minimum;

        max = maximum;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (long possiblePrime = min; possiblePrime <= max; possiblePrime++)
        {
            bool isPrime = true;
            for (long possibleFactor = 2; possibleFactor <= (long)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(possiblePrime)); possibleFactor++)
            {
                long remainderAfterDivision = possiblePrime % possibleFactor;
                if (remainderAfterDivision == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    yield return possiblePrime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code from main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Primes primesFrom2To1000 = new Primes(2, 1000);
        foreach (long i in primesFrom2To1000)
            Console.Write("{0}  ", i);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Not only does it give multiple values, it also gives non-prime values, like 975 and 999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `if (isPrime)` part out of the factoring loop. (It's easier to notice things like this if you create a separate `bool isPrime(int n)` method.)